# How to select a data from a subset

Tags: python

I make an array of Customer Name and Segment to know this customer belongs to which segment. However, I am trying to select the customer name only in the array of customer name and segment as the X data for my scatter plot graph, using the customer name as X and profit as Y.

Therefore I used this code :

```
customer = store[["Customer Name","Segment"]].values
for i in range (0,10378):
    name = []
    name[:,i] = customer[:,0]
```

It returns me this instead :

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: `name` is a list and you're treating it as a 2d numpy array. Realizing that `(:,i)` is a tuple, the error should be straight forward.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. Also, `store` is not defined. Is it important? See [mre] for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is here

```
name[:,i] = customer[:,0]
```

in list slicing `list[start:end:steps]` start, end, steps must be `integer`.
but you have constructed the `tuple` by using comma`(,)` in before `i` and `0`

Correct syntax should be:

```
name[:i] = customer[:0]
```

**UPDATE**

Also this line of code just shrinking the `name` list to an empty list. wondering what's the purpose you have with this line of code

Comment: Calling `name[:i]` on an empty list returns an empty list. And `customer[:0]` is an empty array. There's lacking some detail in the question, but the last line in this answer doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user2653663, yes it shrinking the name list to an empty list. Thanks

Comment: @beer44 I would like to have my arraylist consist of the customer name and segment but only selects the customer name data so that when i plot it on my scatter plot graphs where X : customer name and Y : Profit,  but the point also states the segment of which this customer is from